# Installing plugins in Codeigniter 2.0.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use the plugin here (http://shuvankar.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/codeigniter-geo-ip-location/) but i cannot find a /systems/plugin folder. Where should I place this plugin file?

Additionally, how do I auto-load this plugin? There is no option for autoloading plugins, just helpers and libraries...

Btw, what is the difference between plugins and libraries?

I'm using Codeigniter 2.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugins have been phased out as of 2.0 as NiLL has said. However this does not mean you can't use plugins, just make it a helper instead which is the exact same thing, hence why plugins were removed.

Rename the file to geoip_helper.php and place it into your application/helpers directory and then in your autoload.php you should see the option of autoloading a helper and put "geoip" into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin had been removed in 2.00 version, see here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html