# Does CodeIgniter have plugins / extensions / modules?

Tags: codeigniter, plugins, reusability

I am looking at few `PHP` frameworks and noticed that they all offer re-usable, community-contributed code in various forms:

-**Symfony 2** (bundles): http://knpbundles.com/
-**Zend Framework 2** (modules): http://modules.zendframework.com/
-**CakePHP** (plugins): http://plugins.cakephp.org/
-**Yii Framework** (extensions): http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/

but I can't find anything for Code Igniter (*I saw in [this SO post that Code Igniter used to have plugins that were replaced by helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036648/installing-plugins-in-codeigniter-2-0-2), but when I google for "Code Igniter helpers" or "Code Igniter plugins" I can't find any repositories*).

**What is the name for Code Igniter community-contributed and reusable libraries? Can you share a link to their main repository?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can have a look at [sparks](http://getsparks.org/) and [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc).

Comment: That's more like it :) They seem to be calling these plugins "packages", hence why I was struggling to find something. The list of featured packages looks a bit shy (http://getsparks.org/packages/browse/featured). Is it an impression or is there less to re-use (or not as easily) with the `CodeIgniter` world (compared with `Symfony` or `CakePHP`) ?

Comment: You are correct. In CodeIgniter world it does not exist something powerful like symfony's bundles ( _I'm not familiar with CakePHP_ ). From my point of view the main cause for this is [EllisLab](http://ellislab.com/), who refuses to use the _new and shiny_ things from PHP world, like namespaces, composer, re-usable libraries, etc. The community tried in the past to update CI codebase, but EllisLab refused most of those changes.

Comment: Interesting, especially when you see that `CodeIgniter` has almost as many forks (2035) as `Symfony` (2093), leading to think that community  input would be important. Intriguing I must say.

Comment: I imagine they have refused the changes because they do not want codeigniter to compete with expression engine.

Comment: Hence the reason why they're being very stupid. Look at wordpress! I bet they're jealous.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't find this? https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/_pages

Also checkout [their forums](http://ellislab.com/forums) too.

The previous name `plugin` within codeigniter didn't really mean the same thing as plugins for Cake or Bundles for Symfony

Comment: Thanks for the wiki page but most the links it contains refer to "how to" documentation rather than reusable libraries (although I agree there are some).

Answer (score 2):

check this one [awesome codeigniter](https://github.com/codeigniter-id/awesome-codeigniter) there is a list of different resources for CodeIgniter